# What happens to disputed flags?

Tags: support, flagging, disputed-flags

Wondering what a disputed flag does to a user? I flagged a question, it is disputed, and now the question is closed. What happens to the disputed flag in my profile?

Comment: I've had the same thing happen as well, I guess just like most other users - more than one flag that's marked as disputed but the question/answer's been closed/deleted nevertheless. For Qs/As where I *really* felt my flag was warranted I find the disputed note quite irritating (especially considering the final outcome was what I requested/suggested anyway), but it is what it is and thankfully there aren't too many.

Answer (score 8):

A disputed flag means that a post that you had flagged was declared as an "invalid flag" flag by a 10K+ user.

In addition, an edit on a post which was flagged as "Very Low Quality" will result in the VLQ flag being marked as disputed.

Functionally, there's no benefit or penalty arising from a disputed flag to your profile

Answer (score 7):

Nothing happens for now. Moderators can see in your profile that you had flags disputed, that's about it.

If this would happen quite a bit more, to the point where a substantial amount of your flags are disputed, you'd probably get a message from the moderation team.

But, so far, nothing to worry about. Everybody makes mistakes.

Comment: ffffuuuuu I leave the post for 6+ hours, no one posts an answer only to be beaten by 6 seconds :-<

Comment: @Sathya: lol I was as surprised as you :D